# How to work with country addresses in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm making Spring Boot and Thymeleaf web app and I want to ask you for advice about persisting addresses in the database. My question is how would you store the addresses for these two entities.

I have a `real estate` and `user` entity.

Should I put in both entities fields `state`, `city`, `street`, etc, or make a new entity `Address` where I should store `address` from `real estate` and current `address` from `user`.

And is it ok to type addresses manually or is there some free API with country and addresses I can use?
Do you have some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is opinion based. IMHO, you could create an `Address` entity, and as such your RealEstate and User could have `@OneToOne` relation to `Address`.

To retrieve a list of Countries, `String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();`

However in terms of Addresses, this is country/region specific, and it would need to be entered by the User.